# Ударение в фамилии Таннер

Tags: орфоэпия

Где ставится ударение в фамилии Таннер?

Comment: Спросите у носителя.

Comment: Обычно, чтобы не ошибиться в произношении, нужно спросить о нем у носителя фамилии. Поэтому на этот вопрос нельзя дать единственно правильного ответа.

Answer (score 3):

**Можно сравнить с фамилией известных людей.**

Вя́йнё А́льфред Та́ннер (фин. Väinö Alfred Tanner; до 1895 носил фамилию Томассон 12 марта 1881, Гельсингфорс, Великое княжество Финляндское — 19 апреля, 1966, Хельсинки, Финляндия) — финский государственный деятель, пионер кооперативного движения, лидер социал-демократической партии, Премьер-министр Финляндии в 1926—1927 гг.

Comment: Святое правило: ищи прецедент! )))

Answer (score 2):

В комедийном телесериале «Альф» (США, шёл с 1986 по 1990 год) уже на 20-й минуте звучит имя хозяйки дома Таннеров — миссис Таннер с ударением на первом слоге. Перевод профессиональный, многоголосый. Можно доверять.

Comment: Если бы сериал был франкоязычным, ударение было бы на последнем слоге. Хотя фамилия явно не французского происхождения, распространена(согласно моему скромному опыту)  на германо-англо-язычных территориях.

Comment: Если интересно значение: сущ. кожевенник, кожевник, дубильщик.